# Child theme error "Template is missing"

Tags: child-theme

I created a child theme of twentytwelve using the following in style.css:

```
/*
Theme Name: WAMSA
Template: twentytwelve
version: 0.1
*/

@import url("../twentytwelve/style.css");
```

In Appearance > Theme, the template is listed with error:

> The following themes are installed but incomplete. Themes must have a
>   stylesheet and a template.
>
> Description: Template is missing.

The [codex says](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) only a style.css file is required, which is what I have.

I uninstalled and reinstalled TwentyTwelve theme, without a change.

Why is my child theme not being recognised?

**Update.**

Here is what I am doing to generate this problem.

1. Twenty Twelve theme is installed.
2. I create a folder on my local computer, and create a style sheet style.css inside this folder.
3. I place the code above into style.css, then I FTP the folder I created up into /wp-content/themes.
4. When I go to Appearance > Themes, I receive the errors above.

**Update2**

If I upload this child theme to a different Wordpress installation, it does not become broken.

Comment: Where is your `style.css` located? Did you create a new folder just as the twentytwelve folder?

Comment: It is in it's own folder, called WAMSA.

Comment: Well, your code is okay... perhaps you can try to create a child from another theme, just to see if it'll work...

Comment: Copying your code snippet exactly works just fine for me. Are you sure your folder structure is ok? Do you _have_ Twenty Twelve theme available in installation?

Comment: Yes, @Rarst, twentytwelve is there.  I created a child theme of twentyeleven as well, and receive the same error.  twentyeleven is there too.

Comment: You are doing _something_ wrong. Please add what are you doing step by step to the question (folder structure, etc).

Comment: @Rarst: I've added an update to the question above.

Comment: What is different about install which breaks it?

Comment: @Rarst: nothing that I can think of.  Both WP 3.5.2.

Comment: @Steve At least you can try to get rid of the uppercase letters. Try to rename the template and folder name like this `wamsa` and make sure to deaktivate/aktivate it along the way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.

I went to edit the stylesheet in Wordpress's editor, and saw that the stylesheet's code had been moved onto 1 line.  This meant the top comment section was also on one line, and the `Template: twentytwelve` was not distinct.

Adding line breaks resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the name of the template is case sensitive:

The **original** theme name has an **upper case**. 
I copied passed it to the template name of my child theme but always got an error of template missing. I also added a line break at the end of the file (I know sometimes programmers have issue with the last line).

I modified the Template name - **only small capital letters** - and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I also just noticed the same error and it was due to me downloading the "Google Page Speed Insights" minified version of my style.css